# mysqldump don't work with PHP, just into command line

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### I am trying to execute this command with php:

```
system ('mysqldump -u myUser myDbname | mysql -u myUser -A myDbBackupName');
```

This does not return a error, but does nothing.
The same command executed in server by command line works perfectly.
I am using .my.cnf and i configured the user to mysql, mysqldump and client.
I don't know what is happening. Can somebody help me?

Comment: use `$last_line = system('mysqldump -u myUser myDbname | mysql -u myUser -A myDbBackupName');` to see if there is any unexpected Output. I guess the mysql commands are not in the path

Comment: Return is an empty string. As I said, the command works fine, but when I use it with php nothing happens. I think this problem may be configuring my server, I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have error_reporting turned on? Which OS are you using? There's a comment at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#108713 stating to add `2>&1` to the command, see if that helps anything

Comment: So... 'myUser' has no password?

Comment: lanvin, yes. Because I use this .my.cnf. A configuration file to access without asking a password between the client and the server.

Comment: Well then, I bet that is your problem. Your PHP script probably doesn't have the same PATH and environment and therefore doesn't read the .my.cnf file.

Comment: Thanks guys. I solved my issue. the answer is under.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Put this 2>&1 in the end of the command to force return the output of method exec() or system() to facilit the debug.

The correct mysql command is without space between -p[password]. In fact the password is necessery, independent if you using the archive .my.cnf

Like this:

mysqldump -u user -ppassword myDbName | mysql -u user -ppassword myDbBackupName